Insert into table or table var gives the wrong conversion error when inserting an int into an nvarchar column
When executing the following code in SQL Server Express 2019 (v15.0.2110), I get an error telling me that the insert fails due to SQL Server's inability to cast my NChar string into an int, where the problem is actually I'm trying to insert an integer into a nvarchar column. Is this fixed in a later version of SQL Server?
IF OBJECT_ID('odd_table') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE odd_table
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS isd 
          WHERE isd.Domain_Name = N'odd_table_type')
    DROP TYPE odd_table_type
GO

CREATE TABLE odd_table 
(
    [an_nvarchar_column] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)
GO

CREATE TYPE odd_table_type AS TABLE 
(
    [an_nvarchar_column] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO odd_table (an_nvarchar_column) 
VALUES (N'Abracadabra'), (3);

This results in this error:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Abracadabra' to data type int.

I have also tried this inserting into a view and within a stored procedure, with the same result.

It looks like because you have 2 different VALUE for your insert.  It looks like it is trying to validate the types to ensure they are all the same BEFORE the insert happens.  If you ran 2 different inserts, one for each value, or put single quotes around the 3, I believe it should work.

Not a direct response to your question, but relying on implicit casts is dangerous.

The problem is not the INSERT it's your VALUES table construct. Said construct has 1 column with 2 values: the nvarchar value N'Abracadabra' and the int value 3. Columns can only contain one data type, and if they could return multiple different ones then data type precedence is used to implicitly convert all values to the same data type.
Here, as mentioned previously, we have an nvarchar and an int, so as int had the highest precedence all values are converted to that data type. This, unsurprisingly, generates as error as the value N'Abracadabra' isn't a valid int value.
The fix, however, is simple; insert nvarchar values. So 3 should be N'3'.
